# Separate source files and debug in visual studio

Tags: c++

I wonder if some one here perhapse knows how to put source files and debug files in separate folders in Visual Studio. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Umm... What debug files?

Comment: @rlam12 The ones in the x64 folder. Project\Project folder witth source files\x64\Debug

Comment: What debug files are you referring to? And when you say *"folder"*, do you mean directories in the file system, or Visual Studio's organizational structure as displayed in the Solution Explorer, for example?

Comment: @Ilnspectable in the file system. I know so far that you go in to properties in the project and there somewhere you will be able to create paths to custom folders on the disk. I just want to have the cpp and header files in one folder and the debug files in another folder.

Comment: It's been a while, but that was how it worked when I did it... As in, whether you want it or not, you get a `Debug` or `Release` directory with your binary files and objects, etc.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The output directory and directory for intermediate files has never been hardcoded. Those have always been user-defined, with *Debug* and *Release* being the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

It is a best practice to keep your source files  (which you need to backup or put in source control ) separate from compiler generated files which you might simply want to delete to manually clean your build output.

If you generate a default project in visual studio, that will be the configuration.

Comment: I'd partially disagree with your statement. You surely do want to put the compiler-generated .pdb files under source control. At least whenever you release your application.

Comment: Obviously, it's a good idea to have an archive of what you release. I'm not convinced that putting it TOGETHER with the source files is the  best solution.

Comment: You definitely want to keep the dll, pdb, exe and more when you release a product.  But you don't want it under source control where you normally build it, otherwise you have to check it out to build.